# Is there a way to remap a Google Form query to a different (existing) column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-query

Is there a way to remap a Google Form question to a different (existing) column in Google Sheets? I had to create a new form question, and its data gets placed in the far right column. That's not convenient for our users. There is already a column in the correct place, but the question for it accidentally was deleted from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use QUERY to copy the columns into the order you want on a separate sheet and work on that copy.